# Error 1240: Boot certification verify on LG Optimus Exceed 2

Tags: boot

I've a LG Optimus Exceed 2. It won't turn on. When I plug it into my computer and try to factory reset it is always good to the LG start-up screen. But then in the top right corner it says "error 1240" and shows a boot certification and some thing about verification.

Is there any possible way to get this fixed?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. Its fairly simple.

YOU WILL NEED A COMPUTER OR LAPTOP TO DO THIS.

You need to go to the [LG Exceed 2 Resources](http://androidforums.com/threads/lg-exceed-2-resources.979449/) at AndroidForums, and download the "LG Flash tool 2014" plus a matching KDZ file.

Once you download ask the files you need, open the lg flash tool 2014 out it's pretty much self explanatory... where it says kdz file you select the kdz file you downloaded at the link I posted earlier. Out will be a fairly large file just so you know.

Comment: If people have further questions, they will contact you through the comments on this post. Posting your email will only get you spammed. Also, please don't solicit payment; the whole point of Stack Exchange is to give people help. Lastly, please copy the relevant parts of the linked content into your answer.

Comment: don't like the link at all. This whole thing reeks of spam.

Comment: Becky, as stated above you really need to [edit] your post – for cleanup (which I just did for you now) and for additional details: What should be downloaded (apart from the flash tool, which seems quite clear)? Which KDZ especially?

Comment: you have to get the one that starts with your phone model number